# Journey Mapping Project best practices

Tags: user-research, personas, user-journey, journey-map

Looking for suggestions on process best practices:

In order to understand how clients (e.g. insurance carriers) subscribe to services from a particular company, I need to create a journey map to showcase the different phases from awareness, interest,..,loyalty, leave, return.

Is the best practice to start by interviewing 5-7 participants (prospective clients)? How do we converge all the data from individual personas to the main persona?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't interview personas. You establish personas based on your interviewed prospective user base. So you should start by doing that.
Afterwards you set up personas their scenarios and can start building the journey map.
If you are talking about interviews at the point where you have already established your planned personas, that sounds like an inverted process where you try to build something you want to build and prove it will be good for your potential customers instead of knowing them first and then planning the what.
Be very careful and my recommendation would be to reconsider the approach you are taking here, take it from the scratch and interview as many potential users as possible. The old 5 user rule has been proven to be a hoax in any case but definitely can not be applied here, you should get a much wider info base. Mix interviews with some surveys etc that can get you a wider range of responses.

Comment: I meant interviewing participants and then build the personas. If I interview 10-15 participants, what kind of attributes do I need to group to build the parent persona (or personas)? Furthermore, what is an "implementation stage" in the creation of a journey map? How do we measure their emotional actvity for each phase? Thanks

Comment: What I would do it definitely have at  least 15 participants, and get their demographic background + all the information around the business process you are planning to implement: how they see it, what they want to accomplish. As an alternative to Personas you could also build roles instead, taking out the emphatic part of it but still getting the other benefits or clear user groups. 
To be fair I have moved more towards this approach as Personas haven't proven a huge benefit but take more time to implement. So we use good old roles instead now.

Comment: You can still use any of the two approaches to measure the emotional activity. I'm not sure about very specific methodology, you can gather their viewpoints, attitudes towards some topics and use that to deduct their feelings in a specific point in the journey map - where would you see their highs and lows.